# How to access a packaged CLI tool using Swift on OSX

Tags: macos, swift, nstask, smjobbless

I need to accomplish following three things. I am not sure how to go about it using Swift and Xcode

1. Package an existing CLI tool with the APP.
2. Use swift to issue commands to this CLI app and let it do its thing.
3. Read the output stream coming from the CLI app in real-time if possible.

I have found NSTask that should be utilized, but I get App Previlege Issues and errors. SMJobBless sounds helpful but I am having hard time to understand all this. All I was trying to do was issuing some commands to a cli app that is already embedded within my app package.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to package a Command Line Tool you already wrote and have it run as root, that it is possible to do by installing it with `SMJobBless` but it's going to involve a bit of work. When installing a Command Line Tool in this manner, Apple refers to it as a helper tool. (Sometimes a privileged helper tool.)

For `SMJobBless` to succeed, Apple requires the following:

1. Your app **must** be signed.
2. The helper tool **must** be signed.
3. The helper tool **must** be located in the `Contents/Library/LaunchServices` directory inside your app's bundle.
4. The filename of the helper tool **should** be reverse-DNS format.

   - If your app has the bundle identifier "com.example.YourApp" then your helper tool **may** have a
     filename of "com.example.YourApp.helper".
5. The helper tool **must** have an embedded launchd property list.
6. The helper tool's embedded launchd property list **must** have an entry with `Label` as the key and the value
   **must** be the filename of the helper tool.
7. The helper tool **must** have an embedded info property list.
8. The helper tool's embedded info property list **must** have an entry with
   [`SMAuthorizedClients`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/smauthorizedclients)
   as its key and its value **must** be an array of strings. Each string **must** be a
   [code signing requirement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/RequirementLang/RequirementLang.html).
   Your app **must** satisify at least one of these requirements.

   - Only processes which meet one or more of these requirements may install or update the helper tool.
   - These requirements are *only* about which processes may install or update the helper tool. They impose no
     restrictions on which processes can communicate with the helper tool.
9. The helper tool's embedded info property list **must** have an entry with
   [`CFBundleVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion)
   as its key and its value **must** be a string matching the format described in `CFBundleVersion`'s documentation.

   - This requirement is *not* documented by Apple, but is enforced.
   - While not documented by Apple, `SMJobBless` will not overwrite an existing installation of a helper tool with one
     that has an equal or lower value for its `CFBundleVersion` entry.
10. Your app's Info.plist **must** have an entry with
    [`SMPrivilegedExecutables`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/smprivilegedexecutables)
    as its key and its value must be a dictionary. Each dictionary key **must** be a helper tool's filename; for example
    "com.example.YourApp.helper". Each dictionary value **must** be a string representation of a code
    signing requirement that the helper tool satisfies.

If you want to see a sample project that is configured to satisfy these requirements, you can take a look at [SwiftAuthorizationSample](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SwiftAuthorizationSample).